# Custom region twig template for region into node twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I did add a custom region to my theme via my .info.yml file :

```
regions:
  node_col_1: 'Bloc pour colonne 1'
```

and in my .theme file to make it available for node template:

```
function starterpf_d8_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Allowed view modes
  $view_mode = $variables['view_mode']; // Retrieve view mode
  $allowed_view_modes = ['full']; // Array of allowed view modes (for performance so as to not execute on unneeded nodes)

  // If view mode is in allowed view modes list, pass to starterpf_d8_add_regions_to_node()
  if(in_array($view_mode, $allowed_view_modes)) {
    // Allowed regions (for performance so as to not execute for unneeded region)
    // Liste des régions utilisées directement dans les node.html.twig
    $allowed_regions = [
      'pole_col1','pole_col2','pole_col3','pole_col4',
      'node_col_1','node_col_2','node_col_3','node_col_4','node_col_5',
      'revue_presse','sortie_action','actuAssociation','projets','intervenants'
      ];
    starterpf_d8_add_regions_to_node($allowed_regions, $variables);
  }
}

/**
* THEME_add_regions_to_node
*/

function starterpf_d8_add_regions_to_node($allowed_regions, &$variables) {
  // Retrieve active theme
  $theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();

  // Retrieve theme regions
  $available_regions = system_region_list($theme, 'REGIONS_ALL');

  // Validate allowed regions with available regions
  $regions = array_intersect(array_keys($available_regions), $allowed_regions);

  // For each region
  foreach ($regions as $key => $region) {

    // Load region blocks
    $blocks = entity_load_multiple_by_properties('block', array('theme' => $theme, 'region' => $region));

    // Sort ‘em
    uasort($blocks, 'Drupal\block\Entity\Block::sort');

    // Capture viewable blocks and their settings to $build
    $build = array();
    foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
      if ($block->access('view')) {
        $build[$key] = entity_view($block, 'block');
      }
    }

    // Add build to region
    $variables[$region] = $build;
  }
}
```

Then I try to apply a custom template for this region but it seem not to work,and twig doesn't provide suggestions like for block,field,etc..
My file is called : region--node_col_1.html.twig
His content:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'region',
    'region-' ~ region|clean_class,
  ]
%}
{% if content %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

What do I miss ?
Thanks for help

EDIT: After test, template suggestion work for custom region added to `page.html.twig` but not for region added to a `node.html.twig`...folder structure seem not to be the way,most probably a hook in `.theme` file.

EDIT : someone could help me for the theme_suggestions_block_alter ?

Comment: Are you doing a theme hook suggestion for this region in order to provide custom template names?

Comment: no.I use the native template suggestion of twig

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I didn't added template suggestion via a hook theme so I get drupal/Twig suggestion like in my case :
``<!-- Region Custom ajoutée via le fichier .theme -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--poweredbydrupal.html.twig
   * block--system-powered-by-block.html.twig
   * block--system.html.twig
   x block.html.twig
-->``
But perhaps it's a mistake on folder structure : because I have ``templates/regions`` folder whithout a ``region.html.twig`` like in the case of node or field...

Comment: Those aren't region suggestions. You're inheriting region.html.twig from classy or stable.

Comment: see my edit please.hook is the way I think.

Answer (score 2):

I think your filename is incorrect. It should be:

`region--node-col-1.html.twig`.

[Enable twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) to see the suggestions output in the HTML source, which will paint a better picture of what Drupal is expecting to see as template overrides.

Comment: I changed my file name to ``region--node_col_1.html.twig``  from ``region--node-col-1.html.twig`` thinking it wasn't the right way.Twig doesn't provide suggestion for my case but print drupal blocks within the region.

Comment: No suggestions at all?

Comment: for region, no, for others parts like node, field or block, yes

Answer (score 0):

According to your previous example, you are making the region available in the **node templates** as in this guide:
https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/making-region-content-available-node-templates-drupal-8

You can find a guide for the templates of the node here:

> node--nodeid--viewmode.html.twig 
> node--nodeid.html.twig
>   node--type--viewmode.html.twig
>  node--type.html.twig
>   node--viewmode.html.twig node.html.twig

Comment: I already have a node template according to the content type,it's work and I can print my content region in it.